# How to set a CPT to have a page as a parent, then rewrite urls accordingly?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, permalinks, hierarchical

i have a CPT (called review) for review pages and I want to set these as children of pages i've created.

right now my CPT slug looks like this:
example.com/review/chewy-review

but i have a page on best dog food, and i want it to be a child of that, it should look like this:
example.com/best-dog-food/chewy-review

any ideas how to get this done?  The reason i have a CPT is so i can add special CSS and custom fields like pros and cons etc.

There's also many other pages I may want a review to be a child of, like best-dog-diapers (another page), so it will need to change url like this.

Basically i want the CPT to have a url like a page